# How Do I Add Google Analytics OnClick To Wordpress Contact Form 7 Submit Button

Tags: wordpress, onclick, analytics, contact-form-7

As above, I need to add the following...

```
onclick="goog_report_conversion ('http://example.com/your-link')" href="http://example.com/your-link"
```

to the submit button being generated by Contact Form 7 in Wordpress.

How can I do this?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using event Listener trigger analytics while click contact form submit button,

```
document.addEventListener( 'wpcf7mailsent', function( event ) {
    ga( 'send', 'event', 'Contact Form', 'submit' );
}, false );
```

REF : https://contactform7.com/tracking-form-submissions-with-google-analytics/

Comment: Hi, thanks for this, I've tried something similar already, so to be clear, does the code you posted replace the requirement to add the "onclick"goog_......"/pixel? Thanks!

Comment: Just put this code in your page and submit form and check in analytics. refer that link i mentioned.

Comment: Thanks you @GNANA - I will confirm this and then accept your answer. However I don't actually have access to the analytics dashboard, silly client restrictions, sure you understand. Is there anything specific in the link I should study specifically? Thank you.

Comment: I've done the following, thanks once again, it's integrated on http://www.portraittwo.co.uk - If anyone could confirm the implementation! I'm learning!

Comment: If it is working for you , You can accept the answer

Comment: I'm not sure yet as I don't have access to the dashboard, I'm waiting on client confirmation. Why they can't just give me access for a brief while is beyond me. Thanks for all your help up to now all the same.